# Unless with present subjunctive

Tags: subjunctives

Is this sentence correct? Is it possible to use present subjunctive?

You won't learn English unless it (should) be important for you.

I have come across this one as well.

The native protein is glycosylated and runs with an apparent molecular mass of kDa on SDS-PAGE, but the sugar mass is not believed to contribute to the target size **unless it should be important for** transport activity which seems unlikely as the N-glycosylation has no impact on the transport activity of GLAST.

Comment: In modern English (unlike in Shakespeare's English), *unless* does not take the subjunctive the way it does in many other languages.

Answer (score 1):

The cited example is a clumsy / antiquated form of "subjunctive", which in any case requires Past Tense / "hypothetical" ***wouldn't*** (=**would** not) rather than ***won't*** (=**will** not)...

[image: img]

...which would be better today phrased as *[You **wouldn't**...] **unless it were to be***...

[image: img]

Or more informally, forget the subjunctive and just use ***unless it is / was***. In the *specific* context, Present Tense (referencing a hypothetical "future") is more natural...

> *You won't learn English unless it **is** important <strike>for</strike> **to** you.*